# OpenGL: blend is disable, but still blending

Tags: c++, opengl

I try to render an object, but I don't want its edge blend with the background.

I use only 2 colors: `red` for the object, and `white` for the background.

When I get the pixels of the frame with `glReadPixel()` I see that there are other colors except for
`red` and `white`, a blending colors. These colors are located on the edges of the object.

Eventually, I need to get a picture of 2 colors only.

Someone can help me to solve this?

(note: I used `glDisable(GL_BLEND)` to make sure it didn't work)

Comment: _"These colors are located on the edges of the object"_. Without having seen a screenshot, I'd say you should disable `GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH`.

Comment: You might also need to disable antialiasing in GPU settings.

Comment: Thanks Krom Stern, it works now!